# Understanding metaClass in Grails tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm currently learning grails, and working through [the guide](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/9.%20Testing.html) on testing.

There's an example provided which covers writing a test for this piece of code in a fictional `BookController`:

```
def show = {
    [ book : Book.get( params.id ) ]
}
```

The guide suggests the following approach for mocking out the result of `params.id`:

```
void testA() {
    BookController.metaClass.getParams = {-> [id:10] }
}
```

As this is a change on the static definition of `BookController`, does this persist between tests, or does the Grails magic somehow automatically clean up in the tearDown method?

ie, if I was to write a subsequent test that skipped the setup of `metaClass.getParams` and that ran after `testA`, would `params.id` still return `10`?

If so, what's the standard grails practice for cleaning up in test tear-down?  It doesn't seem to be covered in the guide that I'm reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an ancient version of the docs covering 1.0.x. Testing support is a lot more solid now, so see the updated chapter 9 in http://grails.org/doc/latest/